# Should I place this plant directly in sunlight?

Tags: containers, sunlight, wilt, shade, plant-hardiness

I have brought a curry leaf plant sapling from the local nursery. It was planted in a plastic bag filled with soil from the ground. I have placed it in a 12 inch pot today with fresh store bought potting mix (cocopeat-sand-vermiculite-perlite-compost-rice husk-neem meal)  Should I place it in direct sunlight (outdoors) tomorrow? Or should I gradually expose it to light? I have read it can survive full sun but I am afraid it will irretrievably wilt. [image]

Locafion- Delhi, India with temperatures touching 40 degrees and full sun.

Answer (score 1):

You can gradually expose but they thrive in full sun. Full sun, warmth is helpful for its growth as it is a tropical/subtropical plant and is native to India. Still if you worry much, you can put it in 3-4 hours of direct sun and then move it away and gradually increase the time in 2-3 weeks depending on the outcomes of the result.

However, it will need watering thoroughly in the hot atmosphere. Don't overwater it though. As you have kept it in pot, make sure the soil drains properly and gets dry before you water it again else you will get a root rot and the plant will die eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the picture, the plant seems to be in an energy positive state. So it'll probably require more a decent amount of sunlight to support the growth. Probably not full midday sun.

But placing it in a location where the plant will get plenty of morning sun and filtered evening sun should do the trick. I.e. Place the plant in an east facing location and not in a south  facing location.